# DataDog directory - listen multiple directories at one host

Tags: analytics, metrics, datadog, infrastructure

I need to know is there a possibility to listen to two directories at the same time on one host.

[Directory (datadog.com)](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/directory/)

I used an example document [`system.disk.directory` - Configuration example](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/directory/datadog_checks/directory/data/conf.yaml.example) for initial setup.
One directory is fine, but I need to listen to two directories.

```
init_config:

instances:
  - directory: /first/directory/path/
    filegauges: true

  # second one is ignored?
  - directory: /second/directory/path/
    filegauges: true
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work fine with the syntax you're using. You can add as many instances to that array as you want

Comment: Do you think that maybe some time is needed in order to fetch data from the second instance?